# Как работать с проектом в Sublime text по FTP

Tags: ide, sublime-text, редактор-текста

Кто знает как в sublime text можно работать с проектом по ftp при этом не загружая его к себе на хост.
Пробовал использовать плагин FTPSync, но как не пытался его настроить он все равно грузит весь проект мне на комп(там данных на 30гб.).
Также пробовал ставить плагин SFTP, в нем можно открывать нужные файлы, но он не открывает проект деревом т.е. каждый нужный файл приходится открывать через меню(что вообще никак не удобно).
Если кто-то работал с Notepad++, то думаю вы знакомы с плагином NppFTP, хочется точно такого же но для subline.
NppFTP почему то не работает с некоторыми ftp серверами(падает при подключении).
Если кто-то знает как можно в NetBeans или CodeLobster работать с проектом не загружая его, то поделитесь как это сделать.

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?